# Cassandra versions supported in OpsCenter 5.1.0

Tags: cassandra, opscenter

We are planning to use Cassandra 2.0.11 but the latest OpsCenter 5.1.0 doesn't support creating a new cluster with Cassandra 2.0.11 package. It shows only 2.0.9. How do we proceed?

Comment: I suggest proceed carefully.

Comment: I mean how to use Cassandra 2.0.11 using OpsCenter?

Answer (score 0):

OpsCenter does support managing Cassandra 2.0.11 clusters, but due to CASSANDRA-8072 [1] you cannot provision new Cassandra 2.0.11 nodes.  If you need to create a new cluster or add new nodes, you will need to do so manually at this time.  For future reference, our internal ticket for tracking this is OPSC-3519

-Mike (OpsCenter team)

[1] https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8072